# Slowing down particles

Tags: particles

I've tried messing around with the settings, particularly under Velocity, but I can't seem to work out how you slow down the flow of particles. I want them to rise more slower/steadier and to fade just above the tree-tops.

[image]

EDIT: Figured out how to make them stop at a certain point, so it's just a case of slowing them down. They rise too fast.

Comment: Did you turn Gravity off so they only fly with their initial velocity? Then you just need to find the Normal Slider somewhere in the particles tab and turn that down

Comment: Yep, the gravity is off and the Normal slider is as low as it'll go - 0.000

Comment: In that section of the Normal Slider: Turn everything down to 0. I would expect your particles to stop moving at all. Then try to tweak Normal or/and Z

Comment: I've literally tweaked everything - putting things to 0, 1, or as high as they'll go - nothing seems to work. o_O I'm wondering if it's because the object I'm using, which is a flat plane in the shape of a 4 pointed star, just isn't taxing enough for my PC to render out...?

Comment: Do you have any kind of force field in your scene? Is frame dropping active in the timeline?

Comment: No, no force field. Frame dropping in the timeline...?

Comment: there is a button... Hover over it to find the one with the right tooltip

Comment: Also did you make sure you were tweaking the correct particle system? It would be really silly if you had this problem because you accidentally created a second system

Comment: Okay, I've enabled Frame Dropping, but it doesn't appear to do anything in this case. Um, just the one from what I can see.

Comment: Framedropping is important if your computer cant supply the viewport with the neccessary framerate. Without Framedropping your animation would just get slower as your computer stops being able to handle it

Answer (score -1):

Adjust the timestamp to .010 then lower the mass to .001 under particles physics. And Adjust the Brownian to whatever you desire... Then lower the gravity to 0... See if that helps...